# Struggling wiht SAP HANA PAL Time series forecasting(ARIMA predict)

Tags: hana

I want to make a forecast graph with ARIMA prediction.

When I am using this code

```
enter SET SCHEMA PAL;
drop type PAL_TS_DATA;
CREATE TYPE PAL_TS_DATA AS TABLE (SID INTEGER, GROSSAMOUNT DOUBLE);
drop type PAL_TS_PARAMS;
CREATE TYPE PAL_TS_PARAMS AS TABLE (NAME VARCHAR(60), INTARGS INTEGER, 
DOUBLEARGS DOUBLE, STRINGARGS VARCHAR (100));
CREATE TYPE PAL_TS_OPTIMAL_PARAMS AS TABLE (NAME VARCHAR(100), VALUE DOUBLE);
DROP TYPE PAL_TS_RESULTS;
CREATE TYPE PAL_TS_RESULTS AS TABLE (SID INTEGER, GROSSAMOUNT DOUBLE, ERROR DOUBLE);
DROP TABLE PAL_TS_SIGNATURE;
CREATE COLUMN TABLE PAL_TS_SIGNATURE (ID INTEGER, TYPENAME VARCHAR(100), DIRECTION VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO PAL_TS_SIGNATURE VALUES (1, 'PAL.PAL_TS_DATA', 'in');
INSERT INTO PAL_TS_SIGNATURE VALUES (2, 'PAL.PAL_TS_PARAMS', 'in');
INSERT INTO PAL_TS_SIGNATURE VALUES (3, 'PAL.PAL_TS_OPTIMAL_PARAMS', 'out');
INSERT INTO PAL_TS_SIGNATURE VALUES (4, 'PAL.PAL_TS_RESULTS', 'out');
call SYSTEM.afl_wrapper_eraser('PAL_TS_PRO');
call SYSTEM.afl_wrapper_generator('PAL_TS_PRO', 'AFLPAL', 'ARIMAFORECAST', PAL_TS_SIGNATURE);
```

it is showing error in

```
call SYSTEM.afl_wrapper_generator('PAL_TS_PRO', 'AFLPAL', 'ARIMAFORECAST',   PAL_TS_SIGNATURE);
```

error is

> SAP DBTech JDBC: [423]: AFL error:  [423]
>   "SYSTEM"."AFL_WRAPPER_GENERATOR": line 61 col 5 (at pos 1844): [423]
>   (range 3) AFL error exception: AFL error:  [423]
>   "SYSTEM"."AFLPM_CREATOR": line 10 col 5 (at pos 193): [423] (range 3)
>   AFL error exception: AFL error: registration finished with errors, see
>   indexserver trace

I am not able to resolve this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

please check the feild names and its data type, should be matching with the parameters, ARIMA accepts only integer and double data type format else it will give indexserver trace error. just check all mapped names are exactly same and data types of input data are in Integer or double format.

Answer (score -1):

```
call SYSTEM.afl_wrapper_generator('PAL_TS_PRO', 'AFLPAL', 'ARIMAFORECAST',   PAL_TS_SIGNATURE, ?);
```